# Table from url using rvest package

Tags: r, rvest

I'd like to get the information in three tables from a website. I tried to apply the code below, but the table is in a confusing format.

```
url <- 'http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9'
url %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Obs.: `tidyverse` and `rvest` have been used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do some cleaning of the table.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9'

url %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  .[complete.cases(.),] %>%
  mutate_all(~gsub('\n|\\s{2,}', '', .))

#   W/L                 Fighter Str Td Sub Pass
#1 loss Tom AaronMatt Ricehouse  00 00  00   00
#2  win Tom AaronEric Steenberg  00 00  00   00

#                                            Event              Method Round Time
#1 Strikeforce - Henderson vs. BabaluDec. 04, 2010               U-DEC     3 5:00
#2      Strikeforce - Heavy ArtilleryMay. 15, 2010 SUBGuillotine Choke     1 0:56
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I thank. But, I'd like to get the other two tables too, they are composed of `Career statistics` and `Height`, `Weight`, `Reach`, `STANCE`, and `DOB`. Any hint is accepted.

Comment: @WagnerJorge That information is not in table actually. Would something like `url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('div.b-list__info-box') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  map(~gsub('\n|\\s{2,}', " ", .x))` work ?

Comment: Nice. I am trying to follow your answer but when I ?mutate_all it gives mutate_all(.tbl, .funs, ...) doesn't this imply table is first arg?

Comment: @QHarr that's weird because it works fine at my end ? Which line does it exactly give you an error? Does it work fine till this part ? `url %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  .[complete.cases(.),]`

Comment: the whole thing works perfectly, hence the upvote. I just didn't understand how the last bit using mutate_all worked. I know what it is doing but I tried to follow the syntax by using the help in RStudio i.e. ?mutate_all - there it states .tbl is first arg but when reading your code, I may be wrong!, it looks like you have a func as the first arg?  Is there more than one mutate_all ? Did I simply misread your code?

Comment: Ahh..I see. Actually, this is not about `mutate_all` but pipes (`%>%`), when we use pipes the first input to the function is LHS of the pipe. So the first argument of `mutate_all` comes from `%>%
  .[complete.cases(.),] %>%` which is a tibble (or `.tbl`) and then we write only second argument in `mutate_all` which is the function. See the same for the first part of `url %>% 
  read_html`, `read_html` expects a string but we don't pass anything to it because the input is coming from `url` as the first argument to `read_html`.

Comment: Aha. Thank you so much for explaining.

Comment: If what is on the lhs is passed to the right with %>% why do you need the `.`  in, for example,  `.[complete.cases(.),]` ?

Comment: ok..looking back now I think I should have used `filter(complete.cases(.))` instead of `.[complete.cases(.),]`, we need `.` here to subset logical values which we get from `complete.cases`. You can do `url %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  complete.cases()` but that will return only `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. We need to use `.` to subset those rows. Here `.` refers to the output from previous chain which is `url %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

The table you're working with is tricky because there are table cells (`<td>` elements in HTML) that span two rows in order to repeat information. When `html_table` strips information out, those individual rows get concatenated and you get long strings of blank spaces and newlines.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

ufc <- read_html("http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  filter(!is.na(Fighter)) # could instead use janitor::remove_empty or rowSums for number of NAs

ufc$Fighter[1]
#> [1] "Tom Aaron\n          \n        \n\n        \n          \n            Matt Ricehouse"
```

With some regex, you can make those blanks into your delimiters to split the cells. Information that applies to two rows (such as time) gets repeated. Originally I did this with `mutate_all`, but realized Event *shouldn't* be split—for that, instead just remove the extra spaces. Adjust as needed for other columns.

```r
ufc %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Fighter:Pass), stringr::str_replace_all, "\\s{2,}", "|") %>%
  mutate_all(stringr::str_replace_all, "\\s{2,}", " ") %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(everything(), sep = "\\|")
#>    W/L        Fighter Str Td Sub Pass
#> 1 loss      Tom Aaron   0  0   0    0
#> 2 loss Matt Ricehouse   0  0   0    0
#> 3  win      Tom Aaron   0  0   0    0
#> 4  win Eric Steenberg   0  0   0    0
#>                                              Event               Method Round
#> 1 Strikeforce - Henderson vs. Babalu Dec. 04, 2010                U-DEC     3
#> 2 Strikeforce - Henderson vs. Babalu Dec. 04, 2010                U-DEC     3
#> 3      Strikeforce - Heavy Artillery May. 15, 2010 SUB Guillotine Choke     1
#> 4      Strikeforce - Heavy Artillery May. 15, 2010 SUB Guillotine Choke     1
#>   Time
#> 1 5:00
#> 2 5:00
#> 3 0:56
#> 4 0:56
```